# Как изменить порядок полей в modelform?

Tags: django

Всем привет!

У меня есть форма:

```
class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    TargetProfile = forms.SlugField(label='Автор', initial='___',widget = EmptyWidget)         
    field_order = ('Value', 'Target','TargetProfile')

    class Meta(object):

        model = Raiting
        fields =  ('Value', 'Target')                                                

        labels = {
            'Value': 'Оценка',
            'Target': 'К записи',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(RatingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Она выводит порядок полей следующим образом:

> TargetProfile, Value, Target

. Как я могу переставить TargetProfile назад, чтобы было

> Value, Target, TargetProfile

?

Пробовал прописывать     `field_order = ('Value', 'Target','TargetProfile')` , но ничего не меняется.

Comment: `field_order` должен быть в `Meta`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, это было первое, что я пробовал - так тоже не работает. Судя по оф док все же похоже, что этот атрибут должен быть частью самой формы https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.order_fields

Comment: Попробуйте `TargetProfile` в `fields` прописать тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать данный способ:

```
class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields_order = ('Value', 'Target', 'TargetProfile')
    # твой код далее
```

Это должно помочь.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Задавался этим же вопросом, хоть он может быть уже и не актуален, но оставлю ответ, может кому-то поможет.

Мой случай был связан с панелью управления, хоть автор вопроса об этом не упомянал, но предполагаю, что его ситуация аналогична. Django, в панели управления, не использует упорядоченные поля формы по `fields_order` при их выводе. В панели управления он руководствуется порядком перечисления полей в следующих местах, в порядке убывания приоритета:

1. `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets`
2. `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields`
3. Порядок определения полей в самой модели

Поэтому, для изменения порядка вывода полей в панели управления, необходимо в классе `ModelAdmin`, связанным с соответствующими Моделью и Формой, переопределить поле `fieldsets`, либо `fields`, в соответствии с документацией Django, в которых поля модели должны быть перечислены в необходимом вам порядке.